# Testing private method using spyOn and Jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs

My functions in `Calculator` class is private and I can't test in this way,

```
describe('calculate', function() {
  it('add', function() {
    let result = Calculator.Sum(5, 2);
    expect(result).toBe(7);   
  });

  it('substract', function() {
    let result = Calculator.Difference(5, 2);
    expect(result).toBe(3);
  });
});
```

my class:

```
export default class calculator {
  private Sum(a: number, b: number): number {
    let c = a + b;
    return c;
  }

  private Difference(a: number, b: number): number {
    let c = a - b;
    return c;
  }
}
```

how can I modify this test with using `spyOn` on private methods?

thanks for any help

Comment: Please share how `Calculator` is used privately.

Comment: Please, provide the code you're testing. It's unclear what you're asking about.

Comment: i add to main post

Comment: Is the class named `calculator` or `Calculator`?

Comment: `Calculator`///

Answer (score 20):

The easiest solution, to spy on your 'Sum' method of Calculator class, I came around would be:

```
jest.spyOn(calculator as any, 'Sum').<do-something>();
```

Comment: This works because you haven't made it runtime private. If you'd make the fields private with #Sum and #Difference this would not be possible. Just a heads up, in case you think private is actually private in JS, it is not. It's TS compile time private only, if you want your classes to truely be secured use private fields (#).

Answer (score 13):

In Typescript it doesn't allow you to test the private method. So you need something to escape from this behavior. What you can do is something like this

```
let result = (Calculator as any).Sum(2,3);
expect(result).toBe(5);
```

I hope that will solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

you can try `jest.spyOn` for get implementation of private method

Class

```
export default class Calculator {
  private Sum(a: number, b: number): number {
    let c = a + b;
    return c;
  }
}
```

Test

```
const handleErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(Calculator.prototype, 'Sum');
const getSumImplementation = handleErrorSpy.getMockImplementation();

expect(getSumImplementation(1, 2)).toEqual(3);
```

Comment: working fiine with addition:  `jest.spyOn(Calculator.prototype as any, 'Sum');`

Answer (score 1):

If it's a private data you can't get access to, then you shouldn't test it because it's an internal implementation that might be changed.

You need to cover public interface of your classes that uses this class inside to ensure that they work correctly, how they work inside is their own business.

Otherwise you need to make it public, or at least to pass it as a dependency so you could use a mocked version of it.

Comment: No, you're wrong, in this case we can use ```spyOn<any>``` to private methods but i don't know how to implmented this here

Comment: Why am I wrong? I say if you can't access it, if you can - of course you can use Spy despite that testing private things is against testing methodology.

Comment: The way of thinking you're presenting here is common. I heard this opinion so many times and I have to disagree as well. Private methods should be tested as Public method should. They too can provide crucial and complicated functionality that if changed can cause application to fail or corrupt data, I don't see any reason they should be ignored simply because there's no outside access. @satanTime

Comment: You didn’t get it. They have to be covered, but via public interface. So if you change private methods but don’t change business logic - tests wouldn’t fail.

Comment: So you're saying that by testing methods/functions that are using these private methods you also test private methods, do I understand correctly?

Comment: Right. If I call public save, I don’t care whether it calls private saveToDb or db service directly. Because both of them do the same thing with different path - they save data - the business goal of calling save. So why should my test fail if someone renames saveToDb to updateInDb, and it still does the same thing?

Comment: I'd say testing private methods result in more clear and easy to read tests and test results. You always know which one of your method is not working correctly, rather that going through the calls and locating where it could go wrong. It also depends on your coding style, not gonna argue that its always better to test private methods but judging by projects that I worked on, it looks like a better option to me. - @satanTime

Comment: Yep. Everybody should use what they find best. Just a question, how do you find zombie code when you cover private methods?

Comment: As @satanTime explain. You cannot test private methods directly. 
This mistake is made because you're the "owner" of the code. Imagine I give a class obfuscated and you need to test it.

You will only know and "see" public methods.

Comment: Well, there are different opinions on whether private logic should be unit tested or not. From one side, yes, it is private and unit test should not worry about it, but automated tools (code quality tools) report private methods without unit test as 0% coverage, so it means it should be tested.

Answer (score 1):

The visibility of TypeScript private methods is checked at compilation time. They can be accessed in tests when type checks are disabled. This includes spying on private methods with `spyOn` but they don't benefit from being spies when called directly.

`Calculator` is a class, it should be instantiated in order to access its methods:

```
let calculator = new Calculator();
let result = calculator['Sum'](5, 2);
expect(result).toBe(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or define interface including method you want to spyOn(),
something like:

```
interface IClassPublic {
  Sum(a: number, b: number): number;
}
```

then cast object parameter to this type:

```
jest.spyOn(obj as unknown as IClassPublic, "Sum")
```

Comment: methods from interface must be public - it is purpose of interface. Question was how to test private method.

Comment: One should not mock private methods, even if this is possible in TypeScript in certain conditions. Private methods are use to build the public methods. 

Testing public methods, make it is easy to change the implementation done via private methods. You can even rename them, change signature, remove them without breaking the public contract.

Answer (score 0):

For typescript code you can try

1. Use technic mentioned in previous message with casting to `any`,
2. Access to private methods via class prototype can be done like this: `Calculator.prototype['sum']`. By using this trick type is not checked. After you can mock/spy or even substitute private method with your own mock implementation and see if it called properly.